# Use font file from S3 bucket with php gd

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, php-gd, laravel-vapor

I am using the PHP GD library for image processing in my Laravel Application.

My application is deployed on AWS Lamda.

I am trying to use custom fonts in GD Library.

The function `imagettftext` specifically asks for the file path. Since I am on AWS Lamba, the path does not work for me.

Is there a way to use the font file stored on S3 with PHP GD?

Is there a way to input the file itself instead of the file path?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question of the reference below, you can download the font first so maybe adding the font in a public s3 url and then run the command

[imagettftext function using font from remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313061/imagettftext-function-using-font-from-remote-server)

another method mentioned in the link below but its same concept 
http://bililite.com/blog/2012/06/04/using-imagettftext-with-off-site-font-urls/